# text-shadow property in javascript d3 parallel coordinates chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to style my chart using JS rather than CSS. One issue I just ran into is this Parallel Coordinates chart that won't take text-shadow property. Any ideas?

[image]

https://jsbin.com/kupaceweno/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set a value of the style attribute, you should probably use `style` instead of `attr`. The following seems to work, in that it results in a change. May not be exactly what you want though.

```
.style("text-shadow", "0 5px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff")
```